# elasticsearch different result of browser and php client for same query

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I run this query below and check the result in returns 144 records, but when I run the query with browser it returns nothing. I know the results must be same in any case this api converts the query like that anyway but results are different and cant understand reason

```
$elasticSearch = new Elasticsearch\Client(['hosts' => ['localhost:9200']]);
        $params = array();
        $json = '{
                    "query" : {
                        "match" : {
                            "logdata" : "_client_"
                        }
                    }
                    }';
        $params['body'] = $json;
        $params['index'] = 'accesslog_index';
        $params['size'] = 400;
        $query = $elasticSearch->search($params);
```

[image]

if image doesn't seem:
the url in browser: http://localhost:9200/accesslog_index/_search?pretty=true&q=logdata:*_client_*&size=100
and result:

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 72,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "accesslog_index",
      "_type" : "acceslogs_june",
      "_id" : "AU6R267Wy2aRfwCng6-y",
```

...

Comment: $searchParams['body'] = $json
Isn't this a wrong parameter name?
Shoudn't be $params instead?

Comment: @MBudnik Yes I edited and now it returns 0 record :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason for this is because the two queries are not equivalent.

In the query DSL, the equivalent query for `http://localhost:9200/accesslog_index/_search?q=logdata:*_client_*` is not a `match` query but a `query_string` query, like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "default_field" : "logdata",
            "query" : "*_client_*"
        }
    }
}
```

From the [official doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax):

> The query string “mini-language” is used by the Query String Query and
>   by the q query string parameter in the search API.